# Trying to add a column of logicals by looping over time in a tibble in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, finance

I started replicating the value factor used by Fama and French in **[r](/questions/tagged/r)** to build a portfolio strategy for my final dissertation.

I have a dataset of monthly market caps from the S&P 500 over the years. I created a loop to determine whether the variable (mkt cap) of a determined observation at a certain date is higher or lower than a certain threshold computed cross-sectionally at the same time (across all the observations of the variable mkt cap at time t). 
To achieve this, I thought the appropriate technique to be a for loop. In this way for each date I calculate the threshold and check the criteria. Unfortunately I am not able to store the logical during the loop. When I print the results I can see what I would like to store but when I try to store I get only the results related to the last step of the loop.

```
for(d in dates$date){
  month <- data_tbk %>% filter(date==d) 
  up <- quantile(month$mktcap, 0.8, na.rm=TRUE)
  low <- quantile(month$mktcap, 0.2, na.rm=TRUE)
  data_tbk %>% filter(date==d) %>%
    mutate(ptf=ifelse(mktcap>=up,1,ifelse(mktcap<=low,0,NA))) %>%
    print
    }
```

Another way I tried to pursue is the following but I got even less:

```
data_tbk$ptf <- NA
for(d in dates$date){
  month <- data_tbk %>% filter(date==d)
  up <- quantile(month$mktcap, 0.8, na.rm=TRUE)
  low <- quantile(month$mktcap, 0.2, na.rm=TRUE)
  data_tbk %>% filter(date==d) %>% filter(mktcap>=up) %>% ptf=1
  filter(data_tbk, date==d) %>% filter(mktcap<=low) %>% ptf=0
  }
```

How should I change the codes to get a column containing the logical 1 or 0 according to the criteria?

[image: data_pdk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a loop.

Assuming your dataframe is `data_tbk`, this code will create new variable `is_higher`. 1 if `mktcap` more then Q80%, 0 if less than Q20%, and NA for the rest.

```
library(dplyr)

data_tbk  <- data_tbk %>% 
    mutate(is_higher = case_when(
                        mktcap >  quantile(mktcap,0.8) ~ 1,
                        mktcap <= quantile(mktcap,0.2) ~ 0,
                        TRUE ~ NA) )
```

If you expect to calculate quantile per date, then add `group_by` clause.

```
data_tbk <- data_tbk %>% 
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(is_higher = case_when(
                        mktcap >  quantile(mktcap,0.8) ~ 1,
                        mktcap <= quantile(mktcap,0.2) ~ 0,
                        TRUE ~ NA) )
```

PS. You need to install package `dplyr`

```
install.package("dplyr")
```

Comment: Just for clarity I want to add that the dataframe shown is data_tbk